# Delay in every sounds produced by computer

Tags: audio, delay

I have a recurrent problem with my computer : everytime I play music on my computer, or a movie, or even sounds in websites, there is a delay (about two seconds) before the sound is launched (the sound is complete, but just launches later than it should). Can you help me with that ?

Sorry if it's out of subject here, didn't find any better place to ask.

Comment: There can be various reasons why this happens. Does the sound stutter sometimes? Are you using a Remote Desktop Connection? What else have you tried?

Comment: What does your actual hardware setup in relation to sound look like?

Comment: How are your speaker connected? USB? Jack plug? Bluetooth?

Comment: This seems too broad to me.